# Identify active users and tables in a legacy database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, oracle19c

I am  working on very legacy database. It is Oracle 19c database.  It contains 120 database users and 900 tables at present. There is no documentation as of now on this database. I must identify following items.

1. How to identify who is using the database and for what purpose?
2. Who are frequently/actively connected  users?
3. Which tables do we access most frequently?
4. Which tables are not in use?

It would be great help if you provide different options & data dictionary tables to meet this.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not collect that information by default. The only way to collect that information is to enable auditing on the users and tables in question. That will allow you - over time - to create a profile of activity and usage patterns.

See the [Introduction to Auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/introduction-to-auditing.html) for more information.